# How do I dynamically denote my object property names?

Tags: javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    var _name = moment().subtract('days', i).format('dddd');
    week_count.push({
        _name: 0
    });
}
```

This is what I am attempting to do - however, this creates a list of objects that have properties named `_name`, how can I go about doing this? I tried executing it like so `{ moment().subtract('days',i).format('dddd') : 0 }`, but this gave in to a Syntax Error. How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't specify dynamic property names inside an object literal, but you can use [bracket syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    var _name = moment().subtract('days',i).format('dddd');
    var obj = {};
    obj[_name] = 0;
    week_count.push(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use subscript notation to specify the key dynamically

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    var _name = moment().subtract('days', i).format('dddd'), object = {};
    object [_name] = 0;
    week_count.push(object);
}
```

You might be able to shorten it a little bit, like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    var object = {};
    object[moment().subtract('days', i).format('dddd')] = 0;
    week_count.push(object);
}
```

If you are looking for a way to do this in one line, then you might want use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Adding_properties_and_default_values) , like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    var _name = moment().subtract('days', i).format('dddd');
    week_count.push(Object.defineProperty({}, _name, {value:0,enumerable:true}));
}
```